# How long is WordPress 3.9.2 supported?

Tags: support

I am using the latest WordPress 3.9.2 and recently WordPress 4.0 has been released. I am not in a hurry to upgrade to 4.0. But would like to know how long 3.9.2 will be supported. Are the WordPress end-of-support times for different versions mentioned anywhere? I looked in Google, but could not figure it out.

Comment: I don't think there is something like that for WordPress because WordPress offer backward compatibility for very old versions too. So you don't need to worry towards WordPress. Although you need to check the same for plugins because that's totally different.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, support is dropped as soon as a major version is released. Actually, in true sense, if you take into account the major releases, support is never dropped, it just falls over into the next major release. A major version are not necessarily meant to just introduce new features in Wordpress, but it also addresses bugs that came from the previous/last minor/major update.

Major updates are just extensions to the previous versions.